# Is it possible to daisy chain without hard-wired addresses?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, i2c

I wonder is it possible to use daisy-chaining, and instead of assigning each slave an address manually, they should be somehow be intelligent enough to communicate with each other?

Comment: (1) I2C doesn't support daisy-chaining.  If you haven't read the [I2C specification](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf), be sure to read it.  (2) In its present form, the question is too broad.  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  What do you need to communicate to?

Comment: Some SPI compatible devices have an In data line and an Out data line where the Out line can be daisy-chained to the In of the next device.

Comment: There are communication methods that allow this  (Ethernet, LON, one-wire) for example, but the choices are highly application dependent. For example, a temperature sensor array not only needs communication ability for each node but the physical location of each node usually is important.

Comment: You could put a micro in the middle of the line but that would be of your own implementation. 1) You don't need to daisy chain I2C, its a 2-wire bus. 2) Sometimes SPI chips have an SDI an SDO that supports daisy chaining (some linear parts do this to some extent)

Comment: least number of pins I2C you need each device to have a separate address.   if you are talking microcontroller to microcontroller you can use serial/uart for example and daisy chain that all you want, no reason to overcomplicate it with i2c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2C is multidrop protocol, on most devices address is fixed (for example DS3231 RTC) while on MCU it set by software. Multidrop means all devices are on the same bus and listening simultaneously while one is transmitting. All MCUs support single Master and multiple Slaves I2C. In such case only Master initiates communication. There is also multimaster I2C setup (any Master can initiate communication), but for example in AVR (at least in older ones) it has some design flaws.

MCUs usually also support multimaster communication over UART, but implementation depends on MCU vendor and is not standardized.

RS-485 is most popular multidrop bus, but needs additional transceiver IC.

Daisy chaining, in terms of communication usually refers to message relaying between devices connected in series. Any interface mix could be used for that.